# Eclipse plugin access restriction

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm migrating an Eclipse plugin from Kepler to Luna and I have these errors in my Eclipse `Problems` tab.

```
Access restriction: The type 'BundleContext' is not API (restriction on required library '/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.2.v20150203-1939.jar')
Access restriction: The type 'IStartup' is not API (restriction on required library '/LUNA/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.106.2.v20150204-1030.jar')
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Access restriction: The type 'SWT' is not API (restriction on required library '/LUNA/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.103.2.v20150203-1351.jar') HiteView.java   /mvc/view   line 81 Java Problem
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Access restriction: The type 'Shell' is not API (restriction on required library 'eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.103.2.v20150203-1351.jar') HiteView.java   /mvc/view   line 38 Java Problem
```

And some more like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: english, spelling, etc.

Comment: What are your dependencies in the `MANIFEST.MF` file? It seems you might need to update their version.

Comment: Build a model plugin project in Luna and **carefully, a few lines at a time,** copy your code into the model plugin project.